# rails: query a postgres range field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, range

I have a table of ip start/ends with an additional range field which is autopopulated on creation of a record, which I would like to query with the request ip when my app is first loaded...but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to query a range type in ActiveRecord

model

```
class IpRange < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school

  validates :school, presence: true
  serialize :range

  before_create :get_range

  private
    require "ipaddr"

    def get_range
      low = IPAddr.new(self.start).to_i
      high = IPAddr.new(self.finish).to_i
      self.range = (low...high)
    end
end
```

migration

```
create_table :ip_ranges do |t|
  t.references :school, foreign_key: true, null: false
  t.string :start
  t.string :finish
  t.string :range

  t.timestamps
```

I've tried using the `@>` operator as in the postgres docs as so:

```
if IpRange.where("range @> ?", request.remote_ip)
  #do stuff
end
```

to no avail. Any assistance much appreciated

Comment: Is `range` a real postgres range type column or just a `varchar` as shown in the migration?

Comment: It's stored in the db as a string and when retrieved is returned as a ruby range object

Comment: Ok, then you cannot perform any postgres `where` magic on it

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: But if you can, there are native range types in postgres which are absolutely great. https://wiki.postgresql.org/images/7/73/Range-types-pgopen-2012.pdf